# Agregar elemento a un objeto que está dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Hola tengo este siguiente array:

```js
dias = [{lunes: 0}, {martes: 0}, {miercoles: 0}, {jueves: 0}, {viernes: 0}]
```

Quisiera simular un sitio de reservas y que cada vez que una persona reserve para un día el valor de la propiedad aumente de uno en uno. Cómo sería la forma adecuada de realizarlo?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás esto te ayude para tu proyecto!

**Código de ejemplo:**

```js
const dia = document.querySelectorAll(".click");

let dias = {
  lunes: 0,
  martes: 0,
  miercoles: 0,
  jueves: 0,
  viernes: 0,
}

let count = 0;

dia.forEach(key => {
  let typeDia = key.innerText;
  key.onclick = () => {
    if (count == 0) {
      let sumar = dias[typeDia];
      dias[typeDia] = sumar + 1;
      document.querySelector("." + typeDia).innerText = dias[typeDia];
      count = 1;
    } else {
      dias[typeDia] = 0;
      document.querySelector("." + typeDia).innerText = 0;
      count = 0;
    }

    console.log(dias);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0404;
}

.click {
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<h2>¡Dale click a los días que quieres reservar!</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="click">
      lunes
    </th>
    <th class="click">
      martes
    </th>
    <th class="click">
      miercoles
    </th>
    <th class="click">
      jueves
    </th>
    <th class="click">
      viernes
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Reservar</th>
    <td class="lunes">0</td>
    <td class="martes">0</td>
    <td class="miercoles">0</td>
    <td class="jueves">0</td>
    <td class="viernes">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente, primero la lista.

```
const dias = [{lunes: 0}, {martes: 0}, {miercoles: 0}, {jueves: 0}, {viernes: 0}]
```

Luego una lista de equivalencias, así si recibes lunes, te dirá cual es la posición en el array, esto también podrías hacerlo pasando directamente el numero del indice, o calculando el indice por js.

```
const equivalencias = {
lunes:0,
martes:1,
miercoles:2,
jueves:3,
viernes:4,
}
```

Ahora declaro una variable solo para probar.

```
let diaRecibido = "lunes"
```

Por último accedo a días en la posición que corresponde a equivalencias.diaRecibido, y una vez ahí dentro a dias[0] en este caso, a la key lunes, le sumo 1.

```
dias[equivalencias[diaRecibido]][diaRecibido] ++
```

Si cambiamos el valor de diaRecibido con díaRecibido = "martes" y volvemos a lanzar la línea anterior, entonces sumará 1 al value de la key martes.

Espero te sirva, sin variables sencillamente tendrías que acceder dentro del array a la posición donde está el día y al key hacerle un ++
Ej:

```
dias[0].lunes ++
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más rápida es dándole el valor que necesitas al día con su nombre:

```
dias = [{lunes: 0}, {martes: 0}, {miercoles: 0}, {jueves: 0}, {viernes: 0}];
```

y puedes sumar directamente:

```
dias[0]["lunes"]+=1;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo basico:

```js
dias = [{lunes: 0}, {martes: 0}, {miercoles: 0}, {jueves: 0}, {viernes: 0}];

//Imprimo array
console.log(dias);

//Sumas uno
dias[0]["lunes"]+=1; 

//Imprimo array con el valor actualizado
console.log(dias);
```